# Angular/Express Redirect Initial Route (localhost:3000)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, routes

Simple question.

I'm building an Express web application with two views/routes (controlled by Angular):

localhost:3000/#/join

localhost:3000/#/find

I want the initial "localhost:3000" to forward to "localhost:3000/#/join", but currently, the page only loads the generic static content and does not include the unique html partial content associated with the view.

I'm using the following code.

```
require('./app/routes.js')(app);

app.all('*', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/#/join');
});
```

The forwarding works correctly for all url (e.g. localhost:3000/blah, localhost:3000/blah2, etc.) -- except for the initial localhost:3000.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer. I just need to include an "otherwise" statement at the end of my Angular routeProvider.

```
var app = angular.module('meanMapApp', ['addCtrl', 'queryCtrl','ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/join', {
            controller: 'addCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'partials/addForm.html',
        }).when('/find', {
            controller: 'queryCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'partials/queryForm.html',
        }).otherwise({redirectTo:'/join'})
    });
```